# Sharepoint - Creating custom PermissionLevel

Tags: c#, sharepoint

We can create a custom PermissionLevel programmatically like this:

```
SPRoleDefinition rd = new SPRoleDefinition();
SPBasePermissions ss=new SPBasePermissions();
rd.BasePermissions = SPBasePermissions.ManageLists;
```

How can i assign the Roles from string variable?

For example, I have saved the ManageLists in variable `m`:

```
string m = "ManageLists";
```

How can i use variable `m` instead of SPBasePermissions.ManageLists?

Comment: This question is barely about sharepoint, I think it shouldn't have the SharePoint tag

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the string using [the `Enum.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx).

```
string m = "ManageLists";
SPBasePermissions m1 = (SPBasePermissions)Enum.Parse(typeof(SPBasePermissions), m);
```

Comment: PRS you should accept the answer. This question is barely about sharepoint